# How do I generate and sum the products of corresponding components of n vectors?

Tags: list-manipulation

As an example, consider the three vectors:

`{b1, b2, b3}, {h1, h2, h3}, {yc1, yc2, yc3}`.

How do I get `b1*h1*yc1 + b2*h2*yc2 + b3*h3*yc3` ?

I mean to get the sum of the products of the corresponding components of all vectors.

Comment: `Total[{b1, b2, b3} {h1, h2, h3} {yc1, yc2, yc3}]`

Comment: Nice thank you very much! I just got on Mathematica recently.

Answer (score 7):

```
a = {b1, b2, b3};
b = {h1, h2, h3};
c = {yc1, yc2, yc3};    
(a b).c

(* b1 h1 yc1 + b2 h2 yc2 + b3 h3 yc3 *)
```

Answer (score 6):

```
a = {b1, b2, b3};
b = {h1, h2, h3};
c = {y1, y2, y3};

Plus @@ Times @@ {a, b, c}
```

b1 h1 y1 + b2 h2 y2 + b3 h3 y3

Answer (score 4):

Variations using `*Thread` functions:

```
a = {b1, b2, b3};
b = {h1, h2, h3};
c = {y1, y2, y3};

Total@MapThread[Times, {a, b, c}]

Thread[Times[a, b, c]] // Total
```

or

**Using `Fold`:**

```
Plus @@ Fold[Times, {a, b, c}]
```

---

*Result:*

> b1 h1 yc1 + b2 h2 yc2 + b3 h3 yc3

Answer (score 2):

```
a = {b1, b2, b3};
b = {h1, h2, h3};
c = {y1, y2, y3};
```

---

Using `Outer`:

```
Total@Nest[Diagonal, Outer[Times, a, b, c], 2]

(*b1 h1 y1 + b2 h2 y2 + b3 h3 y3*)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
☺ = +## & @@ (1 ##) &;


☺[{b1, b2, b3}, {h1, h2, h3}, {yc1, yc2, yc3}]
```

> ```
> b1 h1 yc1 + b2 h2 yc2 + b3 h3 yc3
> ```