# How does this code work?

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, core-language

I saw [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/220758/how-do-i-generate-and-sum-the-products-of-corresponding-components-of-n-vectors/298141#298141) thread and upvoted many answers there.
Below is the answer by `kglr` (not my most favorite answer there, but it looks fun). 
I wonder if anyone could help me explain how it works or guide me on how to understand it, specificly these parts `+##` and `(1 ##)`.

```
☺ = +## & @@ (1 ##) &;
☺[{b1, b2, b3}, {h1, h2, h3}, {yc1, yc2, yc3}]
```

Comment: This code can be written in Fortran using no more than 50 lines !

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`+##` stays for `Plus[##]` and `1 ##` for `Times[##]`.

So it could be:

```
☺ = Plus@## & @@ (Times@##) &;
```

or even more explicit:

```
☺ = Plus[##] & @@ (Times[##]) &;
```

Comment: Or just `Total[Times[##]] `. Btw., `1 ##` is not really equvalent to `Times[##]`, but rather to `Times[1,##]`. So there will be superfluous multiplications with `1 ##`.

Comment: Or `#1+##2& @@ (#1 ##2) &`